# Selecting Radio Button w/ Label

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, radio-button

I'm trying to style radio buttons by hiding them placing a substitute image in the background of the button's respective label (sort of like [this technique](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953)).  Anyway as a test I wanted to see if I could get this css to work on the radio button label:

```
input[type="radio"] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:red;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't get anything in the above CSS to affect the label.

I'm generating the radio buttons with the following:

```
<%= f.input :trademark_search, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Would you like us to do a trademark search and provide advice regarding any issues we identify in relation to the name you have selected?', input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

It renders the following HTML:

```
<span class="radio">
  <label for="incorporation_trademark_search_true">
    <input id="incorporation_trademark_search_true" class="radio_buttons optional form-control" type="radio" value="true" name="incorporation[trademark_search]">
    Yes
  </label>
</span>
<span class="radio">
  <label for="incorporation_trademark_search_false">
    <input id="incorporation_trademark_search_false" class="radio_buttons optional form-control" type="radio" value="false" name="incorporation[trademark_search]">
    No
  </label>
</span>
```

Anyway, I'd really like to figure out what I'm missing here.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You should read up about `+` selector in CSS. This does not select the parent, it will select a sibling (That immediately follows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how this works is `+` will select a sibling that immediately follows.

This is the correct way to use it.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}
div + span {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

---

And then this is how you was trying to use it (selecting the parent)

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}
div + span {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

As you can see that will not work.

---

And the immediately follows part demo here, I have put a `<i>` between. As you can see it will not work.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}
div + span {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<i></i>
<span></span>
```